# How to set up Presto server on aws emr and allow data access to users through a connection string

Tags: connection-string, presto, presto-jdbc

I am new to Presto and Hive. I am working on a project where I have to use aws and set up an emr cluster that runs both presto and hive. I am able to do this and I can access hive from the cli, I can also access presto from both the cli and the web UI. However my challenge is being able to set up a basic connection string. I would like to be able to connect to presto using tools like DBeaver or DataGrip or even Python to allow users access the data on the presto server using the connection string. I am not sure how to go about the connection string part at all, any leads to guide me would be helpful.

I have gone through the documentation and searched the web and I can not find a clear explanation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The connection string connects to the master node, I simply had to allow TCP traffic to the node through the presto port.